# Add component to JDeveloper Entity attributes details "Control type" property

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How can I add my own declarative component to list in JDeveloper in ADF entity attributes page, when I select control type property?

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
All you can do is to drop a standard ADF component, then change it manually.

Or, if you don't want to change it manually, you can build your own ADF Audit Rule to replace it for you using an automated fix:

http://jonasdegraaff.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/adf-11g-create-your-own-audit-rules-and.html

Comment: So where is the JDeveloper save this default mapping?? i mean the date type mapped to date picker control , string mapped to text input ??

Comment: I remember I was registering a SR with Oracle on this matter and their reply was that such customization is not supported. Of course, if you are patient enough and start looking across Jdeveloper files,  there is a chance you will find such mapping. If you do, please share it with us!